# Assigning value to an index in a struct pointer array inside of a struct pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I currently having a problem assigning a `NODE` type object to a `NODE*` array that is inside of an `INV_PAGE_TABLE` structure.

The structures look as follows:

```
typedef struct node {
    int pid;
    int p;
    int offset;
    unsigned TAG;
} NODE;

typedef struct invTablePage {
    NODE *pageTable;
    int frameSize;
    int currentSize;
    int totalSize;
    int oldest;
    int maxIndex;
} INV_PAGE_TABLE;
```

The `invTablePage` is allocated as follows:

```
void initInverted(INV_PAGE_TABLE *invTable, int memSize, int frameSize) {
    //Malloc inverted page table
    invTable = malloc(sizeof(struct invTablePage));
    //Save frameSize
    invTable->frameSize = frameSize;
    //Save totalSize
    invTable->totalSize = memSize / frameSize - 1;
    //Save currentSize
    invTable->currentSize = 0;
    //Set oldest
    invTable->oldest = 0;
    //Malloc array inside of page table
    invTable->pageTable = malloc(sizeof(NODE) * invTable->totalSize);
}
```

And finally the method which invokes a Segmentation Fault

```
void addToPageTable(struct invTablePage *invTable, NODE *node) {
    NODE tempNode;
    //If pageTable is not full
    int currentSize = invTable->currentSize;

    if (invTable->currentSize != invTable->totalSize) {
        //Add Entry at index of currentSize

        /*FOLLOWING LINE CRASHES PROGRAM*/
        invTable->pageTable[currentSize] = node;

        //Update currentSize
        invTable->currentSize++;
        //If pageTable is full
    } else {
        //Set temp to oldest
        tempNode = invTable->pageTable[invTable->oldest];
        //Set oldest to node
        invTable->pageTable[invTable->oldest] = *node;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is wrong on line `invTable->pageTable[currentSize] = node;`, you meant `invTable->pageTable[currentSize] = *node;`?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that, in an array [10] for example, index runs from 0 to 9

So your total size should be invTable->totalSize = memSize/frameSize;
And currentSize shouldn't exceed invTable->totalSize - 1.
But I think you have to allocate memSize/frameSize and not memSize/frameSize - 1...

I'm not sure my answer is right, try some printf...